Finding the particular solution to 2nd order ODE.
I have a non homogeneous problem:
$$
y''(r) + \frac{2}{r} y'(r) = \frac{Q(r)}{k_i}
$$
where $ y(r) = T(r, \theta)$ is the function to be solved and Q(r) is a function given as:
$$
Q(r) = (\frac{r-t+l}{t})^\alpha * cos(\theta)
$$
The complementary solution to the homegenous equation:$$
y''(r) + \frac{2}{r} y'(r) = 0
$$
is obtained through the implementation of Spherical Harmonics, and is given as:
$$
y_c = (C_1*r + \frac{C_2}{r^2})*cos(\theta)
$$
Can someone please help me to find the particular solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Use $ signs around mathematical formulas inline or $$ if you want big equation in the text

Thanks @Andrei! I'll keep that in mind.

HINT
Multiply both sides by $r^{2}$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
r^{2}y'' + 2ry' = \frac{r^{2}Q(r)}{k_{i}} & \Longleftrightarrow (r^{2}y')' = \frac{r^{2}Q(r)}{k_{i}}
\end{align*}

Thanks @Atila! This has helped me.

@S.Pant you are welcome! I am glad I could help.
